# Refining union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

This does not compile:

```
type FormatTypes = {
    text: string,
    binary: Array<number>
};

type Format = keyof FormatTypes;
type FormatType<F extends Format> = FormatTypes[F];

type Formatter = {
    format<F extends Format>(param: string, format: F): FormatType<F>
}

const blah: Formatter = {
    format(param, format) {
        return format === 'text' ? param : [1, 0, 0, 1];
    }
};
```

What gives? I get this error:

```
Type '<F extends "text" | "binary">(param: string, format: F) => string | number[]' is not assignable to type '<F extends "text" | "binary">(param: string, format: F) => FormatType<F>'.
  Type 'string | number[]' is not assignable to type 'FormatType<F>'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FormatType<F>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & number[]'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.(2322)
input.tsx(10, 5): The expected type comes from property 'format' which is declared here on type 'Formatter'
```

Why is the conditional statement not refining the type of the `format` parameter so that the return value is one of the `FormatTypes[F]` values? Is there a way for me to get the desired behavior?

Comment: It seems that the ternary is being seen as `string | number[]`... maybe explicit and verbose if statements would fix it? Edit: no, they didn't, TS is mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think not like `keyof` parameter, `FormatType<F>` doesn't necessarily reduce to `string | Array<number>` here.

By changing your last `blah` object like below, I managed to make the program compile.

I couldn't find any less verbose way to handle this.

```
// option 1. make use of `format` parameter
const blah: Formatter = {
  format: (param, format) => {
    return (format === "text" ? param : [1, 0, 0, 1]) as FormatType<typeof format>
  },
};

//option 2. use generic here again
const blah: Formatter = {
  format: <F extends Format>(param:string, format:F) => {
    return (format === "text" ? param : [1, 0, 0, 1]) as FormatType<F>
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) here when you define `FormatType`:

```
type FormatType<F extends Format> = FormatTypes[F];
```

This only works for actual *indexed access* – ie the compiler can check if typings are correct when an object property is accessed, but not at general times in all kinds of control structures. The compiler isn't sophisticated enough to trace all routes through the program to check all output correct types.

In practice, this means that to achieve what you want you need to rewrite using actual indexed access, ie:

```
const blah: Formatter = {
    format(param, format) {
        const formatTypes = {
            text: param,
            binary: [1, 0, 0, 1]
        }
        return formatTypes[format]
    }
};
```